# Уроки по html

Tags: html

У меня такая просьба к вам: дайте какие-нибудь уроки по html, чтобы было понятно, как создать шаблон сайта. Буду благодарен, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Лови, [Самоучитель HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml).
Там же и в PDF скачать можно.

Comment: Очень хороший справочник и самоучитель

Answer (score 1):

Просто про HMTL можно почитать на [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), там хорошие примеры =)

Answer (score 1):

Если ты новичёк, то тогда тебе [сюда](http://postroika.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, [Хорошо и доступно все описано](http://www.zvirec.com/html_sod.php). Там также есть уроки по созданию шаблонов